How to fix Maximum content display time component (LCP) in pagespeed
tags img: Component Maximum content display time - 7,580 milliseconds
in desktop lcp score in 1.9sec which is good score but for mobile lcp score is greater than 2.6sec how can i fix lcp score for mobile
<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme slideshow owldemo" id="owl-slider">
    @foreach (var slider in sliders)
    {  
        <div class="bgr-slider">
            <div class="col-md-12 mgr-sl ">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                    <div class="item__left">
                        <img fetchpriority="low" class="" src="@slider.Image" alt="@slider.Title"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                    <div class="one_half item__right">
                        <h4>@slider.Title</h4>
                        <h5>@Html.Raw(slider.Description)</h5>
                        <a href="@slider.Link" class="btn btn-primary btn-ogre" target="_self"> Dùng thử</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
</div>

How can I fix it, my website is: https://asiky.com/
I tried using the "fetchpriority" attribute but it didn't seem to increase the score

fetchpriority should be "high" for the LCP element, not "low", since we want it to load as quickly as possible. Since this is in a loop, you'll need to use your templating language to conditionally set the fetchpriority attribute to "high" for only the first slider.
It looks like you may be using Razor. If so you could switch from a foreach loop to a simple for loop so that you can use i == 0 to check if it's the first slider in the list, maybe something like this (not tested):
<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme slideshow owldemo" id="owl-slider">
    @for (var i = 0; i < sliders.Count; i++)
    {  
        var slider = sliders[i];

        //...
        
        <img @(i == 0 ? "fetchpriority=\"high\"" : "") class="" src="@slider.Image" alt="@slider.Title"/> 


Also this way we're not explicitly deprioritizing the images in the next slides, since images are low priority by default and we would want them to be loaded by the time the carousel automatically advances.
